# How to test Subscription in AWS AppSync Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I have written the following subscription and mutation code in the App Sync Console:

```
subscription SubscribeToCreateDoctor {
  
  subscribeToCreateDoctor {
       id
       name
  }
     
}

mutation CreateDoctor {

      createDoctor(
        input: {
          name: "sanju", 
          registrationNo: "some value",
          speciality: "some value",
          profilePic: "some value",
          placeOfResidence: "some value", 
          medicalCenter: "some value",
          direction: "some value",
          municipality: "some value",
          isAvailable: "No",
        }) {
         id
         name
        
       }
}
```

In the schema, I have defined both the mutation and subscription:

```
type Subscription {
    
    subscribeToCreateDoctor: Doctor
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createDoctor"])
}

type Mutation {
    
    createDoctor(input: CreateDoctorInput!): Doctor

}
```

When I test the CreateDoctor mutation in the App Sync console, I get the following response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createDoctor": {
      "id": "5845c994-2389-4df9-8a3e-e13dc24b0153",
      "name": "Sanju"
    }
  }
}
```

However, I don't see any logs getting printed for the subscription in AWS App Sync console. The same if I test in the React Native Client app, the subscription event is triggered.

**As per AWS docs it possible to test subscription in App Sync console:**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/test-debug-resolvers.html

> AWS AppSync lets you log errors and full request details using Amazon
> CloudWatch. Additionally, you can use the AWS AppSync console to test
> GraphQL queries, mutations, and subscriptions and live stream log data
> for each request back into the query editor to debug in real time. For
> subscriptions, the logs display connection-time information.

Did anyone successfully tested subscriptions in AWS Sync Console?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It won't work because you try to test mutation and subscription in the same console.
Just open two different consoles. One for `mutation` and another one for `subscription`.
First, start subscription in the first console.
Whenever mutation in the second console start, subscription will get invoked in the first console.

Comment: Working after starting 2 consoles and running the subscription in one and mutation in another. Thanks a lot man. Saved a ton of time.